# Getting "Device Connection was lost" while trying to connect my raspberry-pi

Tags: android, linux, bluetooth, raspberry-pi

I'm trying to connect my raspberry-pi in bluetooth using a USB dongle. I installed bluez, python-bluez, bluetooth, blueman etc.
My raspberry is running the latest wheezy-December 2014 OS. I can discover other devices around me and the bluetooth service seems to be running when executing
`sudo /etc/init.d/bluetooth status`.

When I'm starting the bt-agent and trying to connect the device with "blueterm" app I get toast message **"Connected to raspberrypi-0"** and immediately after another toast message **"Device connection was lost"**

Here is the output of `sudo hciconfig -a`

```
hci0:   Type: BR/EDR  Bus: USB
    BD Address: 00:1A:7D:DA:71:13  ACL MTU: 310:10  SCO MTU: 64:8
    UP RUNNING PSCAN ISCAN 
    RX bytes:32797 acl:146 sco:0 events:538 errors:0
    TX bytes:6925 acl:159 sco:0 commands:146 errors:0
    Features: 0xff 0xff 0x8f 0xfe 0xdb 0xff 0x5b 0x87
    Packet type: DM1 DM3 DM5 DH1 DH3 DH5 HV1 HV2 HV3 
    Link policy: RSWITCH HOLD SNIFF PARK 
    Link mode: SLAVE ACCEPT 
    Name: 'raspberrypi-0'
    Class: 0x420100
    Service Classes: Networking, Telephony
    Device Class: Computer, Uncategorized
    HCI Version: 4.0 (0x6)  Revision: 0x22bb
    LMP Version: 4.0 (0x6)  Subversion: 0x22bb
    Manufacturer: Cambridge Silicon Radio (10)
```

Why am I losing the connection?

Thanks...

Comment: How are you powering the PI?

Comment: I'm using an external power supply which outputs 5V & 2.3A (not USB)

Comment: The power supply seems like it should be adequate, but have you tested it http://elinux.org/R-Pi_Troubleshooting#Troubleshooting_power_problems just because the label says it outputs a specific voltage does not mean that is what the Pi is getting.